# Error: Could not find or load main class [zookeeper-book-example]

Tags: java, classpath, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to run this example [zookeeper-book-example](https://github.com/fpj/zookeeper-book-example)
and I'm getting this error

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zookeeper.book.Master

when I execute this command

```
java -cp .:/usr/local/zookeeper-3.4.8/zookeeper-3.4.8.jar:/usr/local/slf4j-1.7.2/slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar:/usr/local/slf4j-1.7.2/slf4j-ext-1.7.2.jar:/usr/local/slf4j-1.7.2/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar:/usr/local/apache-log4j-1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/path/to/book/repo/target/ZooKeeper-Book-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar org.apache.zookeeper.book.Master localhost:2181
```

I'm using windows so the command will be changed to be like this

```
java -cp .:/zookeeper-3.4.9.jar:/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/lib/slf4j-ext-1.6.1.jar:/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/zookeeper-book-example-master/target/ZooKeeper-Book-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar: org/apache/zookeeper/book/Master localhost:2181
```

and I execute it from the zookeeper directory.

Did I convert the command in the right way? and from where should I execute the command? and how to pass the existing error?

Comment: If I recall correctly, Windows paths use a backslash (\\) instead of Linux's forward slash (/). Also, I think you want to use relative paths instead of absolute paths ( [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)) )

Comment: Thanks, Problem is solved by removing the slash from the jars from their left side and by replacing each colon with a semicolon as this is the Windows separator

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved by removing the slash from the jars from their left side and by replacing each colon with a semicolon as this is the Windows separator

running command:

```
java -cp .;zookeeper-3.4.9.jar;lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar;lib/slf4j-ext-1.6.1.jar;lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar;lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar;zookeeper-book-example-master/target/ZooKeeper-Book-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar; org.apache.zookeeper.book.Master localhost:2181
```